# Does salesforce chat works in ipad?

Tags: ipad, salesforce, mobile-safari

I have added a salesforce chat widget in my angular web application and it's working fine on Safari on a Mac laptop. Still, when I open my web application in Safari on iPad, the chat widget is not showing.
Is there any reason for that?

I connected the iPad with mac to inspect the browser, there it shows the chat input.